# #pragma omp barrier inserted by preprocessor?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have code using OMP with `#pragma omp critical`, but no `#pragma omp barrier`. Nevertheless, in a debug build in Visual Studio 2008 my program crashes with

```
Fatal User Error 1002: '#pragma omp barrier' improperly nested in '#pragma omp critical'
```

Is it possible that such a `#pragma omp barrier` is inserted automatically, maybe in a try/catch block or so? Is there any way to get more diagnostic information, e.g. where exactly that problem exists?

EDIT: This is the structure of the code. I'm using `omp critical` to catch and remember exceptions and when accessing shared variables. It's all one-line blocks.

```
std::vector<RunResult> runResults;
Evaluator evaluator;
std::vector<std::runtime_error> exceptionsDuringParallelExecution;
SomeType someVariable; //used as private variable later

#pragma omp parallel
            {
#pragma omp for private(someVariable)
                for (int monteCarloLoopCounter=monteCarloCounterOffset;monteCarloLoopCounter<numMonteCarloRuns+monteCarloCounterOffset;monteCarloLoopCounter++)
                {   
                    bool hasException = false;
#pragma omp critical(exceptionAccess)
                    {
                        hasException = exceptionsDuringParallelExecution.empty() == false;                      
                    }
                    if (hasException == false)
                    {


                        try
                        {
                            RunResult runRes;
                            //some nested loop:
                            for (unsigned int j = 0;j<10;j++)
                            {
                                while (someVariable->condition())
                                {
                                    for (unsigned int i=0;i<20; i++)
                                    {                               
                                        if (someCondition)
                                        {
                                            //calculate something

#pragma omp critical
                                            evaluator.evaluate(something);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                runRes.setSomeResult();
                            }

#pragma omp critical
                            runResults.push_back(runRes);
                        }
                        catch (std::exception& e)
                        {
#pragma omp critical(exceptionAccess)
                            exceptionsDuringParallelExecution.push_back(std::runtime_error(e.what()));
                        }
                        catch (...)
                        {
#pragma omp critical(exceptionAccess)
                            exceptionsDuringParallelExecution.push_back(std::runtime_error("Unexpected exception"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (exceptionsDuringParallelExecution.empty() == false)
            {
                throw exceptionsDuringParallelExecution.front();            
            }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that gives you the error? Sometimes closing a bracket might mean a barrier.

Comment: I would not expect OpenMP constructs to be present in STL so you should dig into the source code of `Evaluator::evaluate()` and the functions it calls and search for OpenMP barriers there.

Comment: this is only my own code and I know there is no further use of OpenMP. BTW the problem only occurs when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I see four `#pragma omp critical` directives in your code (all but the first) that don't follow the required syntax of being immediately followed by a brace-enclosed block.

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b38674ky.aspx) shows the required syntax:

```
#pragma omp critical [(name)]
{
   code_block
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, I wasn't aware that this is demanded by the documentation even for one-line blocks. Unfortunately, it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: The scope of the [`critical` construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t42b062d.aspx) is a _structured-block_, which could either be a single statement or a block of statements enclosed in curly braces. No braces are necessary in the former case.

Comment: @HristoIliev: If that is true you should file a documentation bug.  Because right now, the documentation indicates that braces are non-optional.